# Perform action from a form or link without refreshing the page/view with django

Tags: python, html, django, django-3.0

I'm developing a project where I need to add members to a group, for that, I go through all registered members and present them in my html template. Each member has the "add" button next to it, but always when doing this it refreshes a page... I would like to know how to do this without needing to refresh, ie click on add and it is already added automatically.

views.py

```
def add_members(request, id):
     plan=Plan.objects.get(id=id)
     users = User.objects.all() # extended django's default user model

     return render(request,'site/add_members.html', {'plan':plan, 'users':users})
```

add_members.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block title %} Add Members {%endblock%}

{% block content %}

       <div class="row">
         {% for i in users %}
             <h4>{{i.first_name}}</h4>
             <form method="POST">
                {% csrf_token %}
                <input type="submit">Add</input>
             </form>
         {%endfor%}
       </div>

{%endblock%}
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do this using only django, since django is by nature synchronous ( in layman's language it means that whenever you want to send/fetch data from the server your webpage will reload). So, you need to use asynchronous technologies like [AJAX](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp).

One way to accomplish what you are trying to do is by building a restful API service only for registration ( using [django rest framework](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/)). Then you can use Ajax to make asynchronous calls to your rest API.

You can checkout this really nice tutorial video by Dennis Ivy for more details on implementation https://youtu.be/hISSGMafzvU.

> PS: Ideally people use a frontend framework like React to make all API calls and they make a separate backend using drf, but since you will need it for just one purpose it is redundant and ajax would do just fine.